# A varchar column is behaving like a char column - why?

Tags: .net, linq-to-sql

I'm working on a legacy application (for my sins!) that started off in Visual Basic 2.0 (!) and has been upgraded through to Visual Basic 6.0 and recently to .NET.

The database server is currently SQL Server 2000 (although I've restored a copy to my local SQL Server 2008 R2 Express instance and it's running in SQL Server 2000 compatibility mode).

The application uses LINQ-to-SQL to retrieve entities from the database.

One particular table is defined as (other columns removed for brevity):

```
CREATE TABLE dbo.Bar_Code (
    Bar_Code varchar(40) NOT NULL,
    CONSTRAINT PK_BAR_CODE PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED 
    (
         Bar_Code ASC
    )
```

It's associated LINQ-to-SQL entity is defined as **Server Data Type**: `VarChar(40) NOT NULL`

---

### The problem

When I execute the following SQL query in SQL Server Management Studio:

```
SELECT MAX(LEN(Bar_Code))
FROM   dbo.Bar_Code
```

I get **13** as the result.

Using LINQ-to-SQL I get slightly unexpected results:

```
// get maximum length of all barcodes
var maxLength = dataContext.Bar_Codes.Max(barCode => barCode.Bar_Code.Length);
// maxLength == 13

// get list of all barcodes
var list = dataContext.Bar_Codes.ToList();

var length = list[0].BarCode.Length;  // legnth = 13
var value = list[0].BarCode;          // value = "9316165196376"

var length = list[1].BarCode.Length;  // legnth = 13
var value = list[1].BarCode;          // value = "9316165196371"

var length = list[2].BarCode.Length;  // legnth = 40 <-- WTF?
var value = list[2].BarCode;          // value = "9317585001669                           "
```

So, for some values in the table, they're behaving "normally" - i.e. as a `varchar(40)` should, but there are some rows with data that is behaving like a `char(40)` column - such as the third row above.

### My guess

During the life of the table the definition for `Bar_Code` has changed from  `char(40)` and subsequently modified to `varchar(40)`. This would explain the padidng of some row values with spaces.

SQL Server's `LEN()` function is treating the column as a `varchar(40)` since the maximum length is 13 for all rows.

When finding the maximum length of all bar codes through LINQ-to-SQL the provider is creating a query similar to the SQL query above (which would explain the similar result).

For some reason when data is queried through LINQ-to-SQL the values are being treated as `char(40)` in some cases - perhaps when they were originally defined as such?

### My questions

Does anyone have any idea why I'm seeing this behaviour? Why SQL Server hasn't "unpadded" `char(40)` values if/when the column was redefined as `varchar(40)`?

Why does SQL Server's `LEN()` ignore the padded spaces for some columns? Is this behaviour controlled by some database/query option?

Why does LINQ-to-SQL not honour the `VarChar(40)` definition of the column type and "unpad" values?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is expected behavior.  When the table was declared as char(40),  the data was padded, when it was changed to varchar(40), the server had no choice but to assume that the data in the column was valid (i.e. that you wanted the spaces).   Check out this sql code:

LEN ignores trailing white space http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190329.aspx

```
create table test (id int identity(1,1), example char(20));
insert into test (example) values ('1');
alter table test alter column example varchar(20);
insert into test (example) values ('2     ');
insert into test (example) values ('3');
select '[' + example + ']', LEN(example) from test;
drop table test;
```

Results

```
[1                   ]  1
[2     ]             1
[3]                   1
```

If you don't want the spaces, do an update that trims off the trailing spaces, or do a rtrim.

Comment: Thanks! I didn't know about `LEN()` ignoring whitespace. I did find that `DATALENGTH()` helps in this case. Regarding the conversion from `char(40)` to `varchar(40)` it makes perfects sense why SQL wouldn't trim space - at least it does now :-)  For some reason I thought that it should truncate the data, but it's oviously trying to do the *right* thing and prevent data loss.

Answer (score 0):

You might want to check that the "spaces" are all the same character underneath.  Try casting the value to a type where you can examine this information to be sure.

I haven't worked with SQL Server 2000, but maybe CAST(Bar_Code AS binary) would give you this information?

SQL Server 2000 Cast and Convert Reference:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa226054(v=sql.80).aspx

Answer (score 0):

I'm not that familiar with LINQ, sorry, but it appears that it is using some sort of pointer by the => notation.  If this is true could it be possible that it is not terminating the string properly and running into another "memory area" until it hits a known terminator?  I'm skeptical only because I would expect the count value to change if this were the case but it's something to consider.